# Word probability problem

Tags: probability, permutations, combinations, word-problem

I am trying to solve this probability problem:

Suppose there are 100 students total in your year at UCLA. Each tutorial group consists of 10 students.
What is the probability that for the next course you are in a tutorial group with none of the students
that were in your tutorial group for Basic Statistics (assuming, of course, that students are assigned
to groups in a random manner)?

Now when I read it I think that it could be solved by just calculating the probability complement of odds of meeting 10 people out of 100 which would be:

1 -10/100 = 0.9

However, this question is from a material which discusses binomial distribution, and combinations and permutations, so I feel like I miss something. Any ideas?

Comment: First off, are you one of the $100$ people?  How many people were in the group *with* you not including yourself?  Secondly, your calculation would have been correct for picking a *single person* to be your study partner the second go around (*ignoring the fact that there were actually 9 in your group, not ten and 99 people other than you not 100*) however your study group is made up of more than one person.

Comment: Choose 9 people simultaneously to be in your study group with you.  How many ways can this be done where all nine are chosen from among the people who you haven't been in a group with before?  How many ways can this be done if we don't care?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are ${99\choose 9}$ ways to assign studuents (other than your self) to join you in any study session.

And ${90\choose 9}$ that include none who are in your stats study session.

$\frac {{90\choose 9}}{{99\choose 9}}$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

- there are $9$ other people in your basic statistics class and $90$ students who are not
- What is the probability the first student you meet in your new class was not in your basic statistics class?
- If the first student you meet in your new class was not in your basic statistics class, what is the conditional probability that the second student you meet in your new class was not in your basic statistics class?
- If the first two students you meet in your new class were not in your basic statistics class, what is the conditional probability that the third student you meet in your new class was not in your basic statistics class?
- $\cdots$
- What is the conditional probability that all nine students you meet in your new class were not in your basic statistics class?